# Calculating same features with multiple training windows in Featuretools

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

Featuretools supports already handling of multiple cutoff times https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/handling_time.html

```
In [20]: temporal_cutoffs = ft.make_temporal_cutoffs(cutoffs['customer_id'],
   ....:                                             cutoffs['cutoff_time'],
   ....:                                             window_size='3d',
   ....:                                             num_windows=2)
   ....: 

In [21]: temporal_cutoffs
Out[21]: 
        time  instance_id
0 2011-12-12        13458
1 2011-12-15        13458
2 2012-10-02        13602
3 2012-10-05        13602
4 2012-01-22        15222
5 2012-01-25        15222

In [22]: entityset = ft.demo.load_retail()

In [23]: feature_tensor, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=entityset,
   ....:                                       target_entity='customers',
   ....:                                       cutoff_time=temporal_cutoffs,
   ....:                                       cutoff_time_in_index=True,
   ....:                                       max_features=4)
   ....: 

In [24]: feature_tensor
Out[24]: 
                        MAX(order_products.total)  MIN(order_products.unit_price)  STD(order_products.quantity)  COUNT(order_products)
customer_id time                                                                                                                      
13458.0     2011-12-12                    201.960                          0.3135                     10.053804                    394
            2011-12-15                    201.960                          0.3135                     10.053804                    394
15222.0     2012-01-22                    272.250                          1.1880                     26.832816                      5
            2012-01-25                    272.250                          1.1880                     26.832816                      5
13602.0     2012-10-02                     49.896                          1.0395                      8.732068                     23
            2012-10-05                     49.896                          1.0395                      8.732068                     23
```

But as you see for one ID multiple points in time a pandas multi index is generated. How (maybe via a pivot?) can I instead get all the MIN/MAX/... generated columns prefixed with last_x_days_MIN/MAX/... so get additional features per cutoff window?

## edit desired output format

```
initial feature 1,initial feature 2, time_frame_1_<AGGTYPE2>_Feature,time_frame_1_<AGGTYPE1>_Feature,time_frame_2_<AGGTYPE1>_Feature,time_frame_2_<AGGTYPE2>_Feature,time_frame_2_<AGGTYPE1>_Feature,time_frame_2_<AGGTYPE1>_Feature
```

Comment: Could you please show us how the desired output should look like?

Comment: Is the edit clear enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by making two calls to `ft.calculate_feature_matrix` with different `training_windows` and joining the resulting feature matrices together.  For example,

```
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd

entityset = ft.demo.load_retail()

cutoffs = pd.DataFrame({
      'customer_name': ["Micheal Nicholson", "Krista Maddox"],
      'cutoff_time': [pd.Timestamp('2011-10-14'), pd.Timestamp('2011-08-18')]
    })

feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=entityset,
                      target_entity='customers',
                      agg_primitives=["sum"],
                      trans_primitives=[],
                      max_features=1,
                      features_only=True)



fm_60_days = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(entityset=entityset,
                                         features=feature_defs,
                                         cutoff_time=cutoffs,
                                         training_window="60 days")

fm_30_days = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(entityset=entityset,
                                         features=feature_defs,
                                         cutoff_time=cutoffs,
                                         training_window="30 days")

fm_60_days.merge(fm_30_days, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=("__60_days", "__30_days"))
```

The code above returns this DataFrame where we have the same feature calculated using the last 60 and 30 days of data for calculation.

```
                  SUM(order_products.quantity)__60_days  SUM(order_products.quantity)__30_days
customer_name                                                                                  
Krista Maddox                                        466                                    306
Micheal Nicholson                                    710                                    539
```

Note: this example runs on the latest release of Featuretools (v0.3.1) where we updated the demo retail dataset to have interpretable names as customer ids.

Comment: May I ask why you do not use `ft.make_temporal_cutoffs ` but instead specify `cutoff_time `?

Comment: you could use `ft.make_temporal_cutoffs` if you want to create multiple cutoff times that are evenly spaced apart by time. This would control the last point in time you want to use data, so this could be combined with `training_window` to limit how far back you want to use data.

Comment: @MaxKanter If i am getting this correctly, i will have to find the duplicated features thus created, like all first order trans features and drop the duplicated ones off the final featurematrix?